# Starting MarkLogic server stalled with "Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/xvdj"

Tags: amazon-ec2, marklogic

Using a free 'micro' instance from Amazon to fire up a quick demo of MarkLogic. The rpm installs fine with no errors.

Some information that may be helpful:

```
[user@aws ~]$ rpm -qa | grep release
redhat-release-server-6Server-6.4.0.4.el6.x86_64

[user@aws ~]$ rpm -qa | grep MarkLogic
MarkLogic-7.0-1.x86_64
```

Starting the MarkLogic server for the very first time shows this:

```
[user@aws ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
Initialize Configuration
Region: us-west-2 ML_NAME:
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_ZONE="us-west-2c"
Instance is not managed
Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/xvdj
```

And here it sits with no other messages anywhere including `/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs` which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290077/how-can-i-run-marklogic-on-aws-ec2-using-my-own-license-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Micro instances aren't officially supported, you can usually start one up. But,  reports are that you will be quickly wishing you didn't.

That said, see the precise instructions at http://developer.marklogic.com/products/aws and, in particular, a disk at mounting /dev/sdf ; the server init script will wait forever to come up if you don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the above didn't help, I've dug into the RPM enough to discover some issues on AWS.

For one, they use some sysconfig scripts to detect if they're on AWS. If you're running MarkLogic 6, these sysconfigs have a hardcoded drive and will wait indefinitely since it probably won't exist. Yours is 7, and still has some issues on AWS. To bypass this, you can make a /usr/bin/is-ec2.sh that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

That will prevent it from doing any ec2 detection. More details can be found on my write-up at [this github post](https://github.com/myoung34/puppet-marklogic/wiki/Permanent-AWS-Issue)

Comment: Marc, thanks for the info. Very interesting. I'm sure it will help someone who's stuck here. Eric's answer above (RTFM!) helped us to get ML running on AWS. We added EBS storage (as per instructions!) and were able to show a quick demo. Eric was right: micro instances aren't sufficient. Not enough RAM. Adding a large swap file to the micro instance helped but we've since moved to a much more robust server.